# How scale fontsize for change size of UILabel

Tags: xcode

My width and height scaling relative interfaceOrientation, but i can't scale fontSize of my UILabel.

```
my_label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

won't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your `my_label.minimumFontSize` is less than the `my_label.font.pointSize`.

You could try something like:

```
my_label.minimumFontSize = (my_label.font.pointSize / 4.0) * 3.0;
my_label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

Or set the values in the Interface Builder for *Minimum Font Size* to something smaller then the *Font Size*.  This way if the label is reduced in width, it will scale the font size down.

Comment: no any different (. i just change width and height and all text not fit in my rect.

Comment: Make sure your using a font that can be scaled down.  See if "Helvetica" will scale down, if it does, then you may need to use another font.